# Text overlay on image

Tags: html, wordpress, css

I am using master slider plugin.slide1 2 3 all have different classes. Trying to place text over the image but not displaying. I tried this 
but could not see anything

```
.classnameslide1:before {
content: 'Text inserted before via CSS';
 }  
and  
.classnameslide1:after{
content: 'Text inserted before via CSS';
 }
```

Comment: add your html with example to avoid down-voted.

Comment: i am trying Insert text with CSS not html which is <div class="classnameslide1">
    <h2>Text inserted via HTML (the regular way)</h2>
</div>

Answer (score 1):

Use position relative of parent and absolute for pseudo-elements, like,

```
.classnameslide1 {position: relative; z-index: 1}
.classnameslide1:after {content: 'Text inserted before via CSS'; position: absolute; left: 50%; top: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); z-index: 3}
```

Comment: so i am adding classnameslide2  classnameslide3  classnameslide4 gives me blank 2nd and 3rd slides